# Iterate All Items In RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, for-loop, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView of CardViews. I am trying to have it where you click on one of the CardViews and it changes the background of that CardView. This part works. Where I am stuck is trying to change all of the other CardViews back to white so it doesn't look like multiple are selected.

I feel the best way to do this is a for loop but I can't seem to find what the for loop should be. I also tried resetting all the CardViews with `notifyDataSetChanged()` but that did not work either.

Here is my `onItemClicked()` function (that works correctly):

```
mAdapter = new TransferCard(list, getContext(), new TransferCard.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
        //What code goes here to change all Views in the RecyclerView to have a background of white
        RelativeLayout temp = v.findViewById(R.id.cardForeground);
        item = list.get(position);
        temp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.selected));
    }
});
```

Here is my `onCreateViewHolder()` where the `setOnTouchListener()` event is.

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.transfer_card, parent, false);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, parent.indexOfChild(v));
        }
    });
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

It seems I am just about there, but I need to know what to do with the for loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you should write your adapter in such a way that `onBindViewHolder()` is the only place where you modify your views. For what you're trying to do, I think the easiest thing to do would be to keep track of the last position that was tapped, and then have `onBindViewHolder()` set the background to black or white based on whether its position equals the last tapped position.

```
@Override 
public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
    lastTappedPosition = position;
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position == lastTappedPosition) {
        // set color selected
    } else {
        // set color unselected
    }

    ...
}
```

You could improve upon this by only notifying the adapter that the old tapped position and the new tapped position have changed (so that you don't have to re-bind every view), but in the interest of simplicity I left it as-is.

Comment: My issue there is that `onBindViewHolder()` is in one class and `onItemClick()` is in another. How do I go around that?

Comment: I got it to work but for some reason it won't work on the very last one.

Comment: If you tap the last one, it changes the color of the second to last one

Comment: Just kidding, it only works on the first two. I only had three so I added more and it only works on 1 and 2.

Comment: If I print to the console the position, the first one prints 0, the second and the rest of them print 1.

Comment: I updated the question with my `onCreateViewHolder()` that houses the `setOnTouchListener()` function.

Comment: `parent.indexOfChild(v)` is **not** the same as `position`. Position in RecyclerView is actually somewhat complicated, but as long as you aren't doing anything too crazy, you can get away with: delete your `setOnClickListener()` call from `onCreateViewHolder()` and move it to `onBindViewHolder()`, and then you can just use the `position` argument instead of using `indexOfChild()`.

Comment: I was assuming it had to do with that. Works great :)

Answer (score 9):

```
for (int x = recyclerView.getChildCount(), i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
  ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Kotlin solution:

```
myRecyclerView.children.forEach { childView ->
    val holder = myRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(childView) as? MyViewHolder
}
```

Comment: thanks @Snort it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have a field like `isSelected` in you model, make it all as false for all the list items.
2. Pass it to your adapter.
3. In you adapter check condition in `onBindViewHolder`:

   `if (list.get(i).isSelected) {
           // change background to black
       } else {
           // change background to white

       }`
4. Whenever you click on an item change just inverse the field item, ie make it true if it was false or make it false if it was true.

   `list.get(i),isSelected = !list.get(i).isSelected;`

Answer (score 0):

```
   for (int x = recyclerView.getChildCount(), i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
       RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.getChildViewHolder(recyclerView.getChildAt(i));
       TextView txtAbc0       = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_abc0);
       TextView txtAbc1       = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_abc1);
       txtAbc0.setText("abc0="+i);
       txtAbc1.setText("abc1="+i);
   }
```